# KendoUI: How to keep open the drop-down list in the multiselect component

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want to the user can select all items wanted from the drop-down list in one time from a multiselect.

That means, not to close the drop-down list every time users are selecting any item, and then opening the list for selecting one more item again each time. The default behaviour could be anoying when users want to select a large number of items inside the list.

Is possible to modify this default behaviour and keep the drop-down list opened?

Answer (score 11):

Since you appear to be using the MVC wrappers for KendoUI MultiSelect, you can do this:

```
.AutoClose(false)
```

to keep the window open while the user is selecting items from the multiselect dropdown.

Comment: Please read kendo docs prior to posting : autoClose Boolean(default: true)

Controls whether to close the widget suggestion list on item selection.

Comment: Obviously, I made an error i.e. the boolean value should be false instead of true. It's not a big deal and you should have just said that instead of assuming I was a complete idiot.

Comment: You're the only one who mentioned that word. I often look to this site for help. Answer posts ARE a big deal to me and others looking for help. IT'S THE ONLY REASON WE COME HERE. Please take care when posting; for us needy people. If we have to guess what you 'obviously' meant to write, where does that leave us?

Comment: All I'm saying is that if you knew what was wrong with my answer, it would have been more helpful for you to point that out directly. Thanks for bringing my attention to it; I've also edited my answer.

Comment: I just looked at your profile an found an answer to a question I had for Kendo MultiSelect - so awesome. Sorry if my post hurt your feelings. I actually was trying to be as fast a possible and ended up spending all this time here...but I did find another answer! So thanks. Weird how that works

Comment: No worries. I confess I was a bit hurt but I've since simmered down and I should've taken your comment in the spirit with which your comment was presented. Please feel free to edit/challenge any of my KendoUI comments/answers. I'm new to it and I've have had to learn quickly. :)

Answer (score 2):

This can easily be accomplished by setting the autoClose property to false like so.

```
$("#multiSelectId").kendoMultiSelect({ 
    autoClose: false
});
```

You can see this at work in this jsfiddle example. http://jsfiddle.net/t6dXw/

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try with the below code snippet?

[Multi Selection Combobox in Kendo UI](http://jayeshgoyani.blogspot.in/2013/06/multi-selection-combobox-in-kendo-ui.html)

Comment: That isn't exactly what I'm looking for, because your solution is based on a combobox. I'm asking for the same behaviour as your solution, but for the multiselect component.